# The equivalent of <generator class="native"></generator> using MySQL and Hibernate3 annotations

Tags: mysql, hibernate, annotations

Starting a new project I'd like to use Hibernate annotations with MySQL instead of the configuration files I've used so far.
And I can't seem to find the equivalent of:

```
    <id name="id" type="long" >
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
```

I tried using:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "native")
private long id;
```

but got:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: native
```

or:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
```

Give me:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: PROCEDURE projectName.identity does not exist
```

Does anyone successfully deployed MySQL and Hibernate3 annotations for automatically generating ids?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prior to version 5.0, using the strategy `AUTO` was the equivalent of using `native` in a mapping. This used the `LegacyFallbackInterpreter`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Since Hibernate 5.0, the [default interpreter is the `FallbackInterpeter`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-auto) which will either use a SEQUENCE generator or TABLE generator depending on the underlying database.

To use the `LegacyFallbackInterpreter`, set `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` to `false`.

Comment: For MySQL it introduces a sequence table rather than using native ID generation.

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to have a look at: http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

Try using `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`.  That should use the MySQL autonum functionality.