# Spring Data JPA / Hibernate generating single id for all the entities persisted within single transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sybase

I have a legacy application which I am trying to migrate to newer Apache Camel Spring Boot application where I am using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate as an ORM framework. `Sybase` is the DB used by application.

I have many JPA entities available where ids are annotated with:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "entity_pk")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long entity_pk;
```

I have a single method where I am trying to create multiple entities and then persisting all the entities one by one into the DB using `JpaRepository save()` method. All this is happening within a single transaction

My issue here is, **hibernate is generating only one unique id** and using it while persisting all the entities.

What I am looking for is a way to tell hibernate to **check the latest value in the primary key i.e. `entity_key` column of each table** and then generate the next value. Sort of **auto incremented** value for each row. Columns are created as `IDENTITY` column in the database.

I do not want to use any custom id generator for this. Is there any way to achieve this just by using annotations and/or configurations?

**EDIT 1:** 
Just wanted to give background on existing legacy application. This application uses `Hibernate 3.x` and uses `<generator class="native">` which apparently works as expected. I confirmed that from existing DB values.

I am using Hibernate 5.x along with Spring boot 2.x and Spring 5.x.

I have tried using `GenerationType.AUTO` along with `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false` just to make sure the `LegacyFallbackInterpreter` kicks in as per the instructions given here: 
[The equivalent of <generator class="native"></generator> using MySQL and Hibernate3 annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212535/the-equivalent-of-generator-class-native-generator-using-mysql-and-hiberna)

But nothing works.

**Edit 2:**
Adding some sample code. It is not the exact code but similar to what I am trying to achieve in my application.
**Entity classes:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "block")
public class Block {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "block_pk")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long blockPk;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "block", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("allocationPk")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Allocation> allocations;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private BigDecimal quantity;

    public void addAllocation(Allocation allocation) {
        if (allocations == null) {
            allocations = new HashSet<>();
        }

        allocations.add(allocation);
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "allocation")
public class Allocation {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "allocation_pk")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long allocationPk;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "block_pk", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Block block;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private BigDecimal quantity;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "booking")
public class Booking {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "booking_pk")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long bookingPk;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "block_Id")
    private Long blockId;
}
```

**Repositories:**

```
@Repository
public interface BlockRepository extends JpaRepository<Block, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface AllocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Allocation, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface BookingRepository extends JpaRepository<Booking, Long> {
}

@Component
public class DbStore {
    @Autowired
    private BlockRepository blockRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AllocationRepository allocationRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

    public Block save(Block block) {
        return blockRepository.save(block);
    }

    public Allocation save(Allocation allocation) {
        return allocationRepository.save(allocation);
    }

    public Booking save(Booking booking) {
        return bookingRepository.save(booking);
    }
}
```

**Service Class:**

```
@Service
public class AllocationHandler {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AllocationHandler.class);
    @Autowired
    private DbStore dbStore;

    public List<Allocation> handleRequest(String input) {
        Block block = new Block();
        block.setQuantity(new BigDecimal(1000000));

        // Persist Block
        LOGGER.info("Persist block in DB");
        block = dbStore.save(block);
        LOGGER.info("Persisted Block in DB with Id [{}]", block.getBlockPk());

        Allocation allocation = new Allocation();
        allocation.setQuantity(new BigDecimal(500000));

        block.addAllocation(allocation);
        allocation.setBlock(block);

        LOGGER.info("Persist allocation in DB");
        allocation = dbStore.save(allocation);
        LOGGER.info("Persisted allocation in DB with Id [{}]", allocation.getAllocationPk());

        LOGGER.info("Update Block");
        block = dbStore.save(block);

        Booking booking = new Booking();
        booking.setBlockId(block.getBlockPk());

        LOGGER.info("Persist booking in DB");
        booking = dbStore.save(booking);
        LOGGER.info("Persisted Booking in DB with Id [{}]", booking.getBookingPk());

        return Arrays.asList(allocation);
    }
}
```

**Driver Class:**

```
@Component
public class Transformer {
    @Autowired
    private AllocationHandler allocationHandler;

    public void transform(String input) {
        allocationHandler.handleRequest(input);
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo.repository")
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Autowired
    private Transformer transformer;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        transformer.transform("Test");
    }
}
```

I have also added this code in Github:
 https://github.com/viveksinghr89/spring-data-jpa-poc

I am unable to replicate it completely but yes partially it is working like the actual project wherein `Block` and `Allocation` are using the same id instead of using different ids as per the latest value in their identity column.

**Logs:**

```
2023-04-17T23:41:05.674+05:30  INFO 21052 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 6.195 seconds (process running for 6.718)
2023-04-17T23:41:05.678+05:30  INFO 21052 --- [           main] com.example.demo.AllocationHandler       : Persist block in DB
2023-04-17T23:41:05.755+05:30  INFO 21052 --- [           main] com.example.demo.AllocationHandler       : Persisted Block in DB with Id [97]
2023-04-17T23:41:05.755+05:30  INFO 21052 --- [           main] com.example.demo.AllocationHandler       : Persist allocation in DB
2023-04-17T23:41:05.761+05:30  INFO 21052 --- [           main] com.example.demo.AllocationHandler       : Persisted allocation in DB with Id [97]
2023-04-17T23:41:05.761+05:30  INFO 21052 --- [           main] com.example.demo.AllocationHandler       : Update Block
2023-04-17T23:41:05.823+05:30  INFO 21052 --- [           main] com.example.demo.AllocationHandler       : Persist booking in DB
2023-04-17T23:41:05.825+05:30  INFO 21052 --- [           main] com.example.demo.AllocationHandler       : Persisted Booking in DB with Id [65]
```

**H2 DB Screenshot:**
[image]

**Please let me know if you are able to figure something out. Would be really helpful. Thank you.**

Comment: Typo? Should be strategy @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) This is the correct value for id auto incremented by database.

Comment: @Mar-Z Yes that's a typo. Corrected now. Thank you for highlighting. Yeah but it still does not work. Basically it works for the first entity that I save within that method but thereafter it uses the same id for each entity that I save. Tried lot of things but nothing worked.

Comment: Please share the code of the entities. At least two of them where the issue occurs. And the service code where you save the entities.

Comment: @Mar-Z Unfortunately I can provide the code here as it's an enterprise application and also access to SOF/GitHub is blocked otherwise would have provided some modified sample.

Give me some time. Will write some samples and update here just to give you an idea of how I am doing it?

Comment: @Mar-Z I have added the sample code and was able to replicate the issue partially.

Comment: I think the problem is not with id generator but with the relationship. The one-to-many and many-to-one annotations has been mixed-up. You want to have many allocations assigned to each block, or many blocks assigned to each allocation?

Comment: @Mar-Z it's many allocations to one block and that's what I have specified in the entities. ManyToOne on allocation side and OneToMany on block side. Its a bidirectional relationship where allocation side is the owning entity.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. The relationship is correct annotated.

Comment: Check the SQL that Hibernate is issuing for the inserts. Either the database logic is broken, or some unseen mapping is causing hibernate to insert the Block ID value as the Allocation ID. The second should be noticeable in the SQL if parameters are logged as well

Comment: @Chris No primary keys are not appearing in insert statements. I do not think DB is broken given it already works with legacy application.

Comment: If values are not being put into the Allocation insert statements, then it is the DB that is picking the value to use, not Hibernate, so it is a DB setup issue. Identity tells JPA that you've configured your database to automatically assign IDs and that it needs to look up the value assigned after the insert - JPA/Hibernate has no involvement in actually assigning them

Answer (score 1):

I have tested similar configuration with H2 file database. Apparently there is no guarantee that the id will be generated without gaps. The only guarantee is that they will be unique.

In my case after the first run of the application with an empty database the ids started with 1 and were incremented by 1. But after restart (without dropping the tables) the id continued with 33, 34 etc.

Comment: I am fine with that gap. My issue is, in my legacy DB there are lot of records already something like ```Table A -> 1, 2, 3``` and ```Table B -> 1, 2, 3, 4```.
Now when my code tries to generate the id while inserting into ```Table A```, it generates id as ```4``` and in the very next line when it tries to insert into ```Table B```, it uses the same id ```4``` instead of generating number ```5 or above```. Any idea how that can be solved?

Comment: I got your point. But it doesn't happen in Hibernate. If you are not setting the id in the entity then Hibernate sends an insert statement without the id. The database (in your case Sybase) will provide the next value for the identifier. If it doesn't work properly please check the definition of the affected table. Maybe there is a (wrong) sequence in use and not the AUTOINCREMENT default. (I'm not an expert on Sybase)

Comment: I checked the definition of tables and looks all good. I tried something different now though. I tried persisting only Allocation instead of Block followed by Allocation. Ideally it should have generated one unique id and persisted the Allocation. But instead I get this exception: ```Generated keys are not available because either the Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS was used or no keys were automatically generated.``` Now I am bit confused as in why it worked for Block and not working for Allocation. Any idea?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. It was nothing to do with the config or setup. There was some issue with the database. I have updated as an answer. Thanks for your time and efforts.